# merge statement err

Tags: oracle9i

I have created two tables with following descriptions

SQL> desc new_emp
 Name                            Null?    Type

---

EMPNO                                    NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                    VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                      VARCHAR2(9)
 HIREDATE                                 DATE
 SAL                                      NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                     NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                   NUMBER(2)

SQL> desc old_emp
 Name                            Null?    Type

---

EMPNO                                    NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                    VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                      VARCHAR2(9)
 HIREDATE                                 DATE
 SAL                                      NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                     NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                   NUMBER(2)

I m using an Merge statment as given below for these two tables

Merge 
   into new_emp n 
using 
   old_emp o 
on (o.empno=n.empno)
when matched then
update
set   n.empno=o.empno,
      n.ename=o. ename,
   n.job=o.job,
   n.hiredate=o.hiredate,
      n.sal=o.sal,
   n.comm=o.comm,
   n.deptno=o.deptno
when not matched then
insert
values( o.empno,
        o. ename,
        o.job,
     o.hiredate,
        o.sal,
     o.comm,
     o.deptno )

when I executed the above statement
system shows following error, i m using ORACLE 9i version

ORA-00904: "N"."EMPNO": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 I get this error with your MERGE statement:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "N"."EMPNO"
```

So try removing "n.empno=o.empno" from your SET clause.